# What is the most efficient way to record video in a browser for purposes of storing on a server?

Tags: java, spring, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm in the process of developing a java web application using Spring MVC that will (among other things) be capable of recording video from a camera on an Android based tablet and ultimately transfer that video to the server (dbase or filesystem).  I see there are a number of tools available that might allow me to do this one of two ways: (1) record that video locally in the browser and potentially upload the final product as a single file to the server (i.e. [RecordRTC](http://recordrtc.org/)) or (2) establish a connection to the server that enables me to stream the video direct, leaving it to the server side to manage the actual recording (i.e. [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/), Jitsi).  However, there are a few gotchas in all of this that are making it difficult for me to determine (1) which way makes sense and (2) which way is actually proven to **work**:

- must be capable of running in any browser on an Android based tablet (v 4.2+)
- recorded video can be anywhere from 15 sec to 15 min in duration
- users will be securely authenticated at login via Spring security; video streams/files need to be handled in that established session (which I don't think is possible with Kurento)
- must be open source

I've been developing Java web applications for many years now, but the video capture and processing component is something new to me and I'm hoping those with experience in this arena could guide me in a direction that makes most logical sense.

NOTE: I am open to other ideas that might make more sense than what I've mentioned already.  Given the direction of HTML5, I thought WebRTC would be the best route.  But given some of the Android based browser limitations, I'm not sure.

Thanks!